# How to calculate current, previous and next year quarter in Shell Script?

Tags: shell, ksh

I need to calculate the current, previous and next year quarter from the current sysdate in the below format.

As per current date (02-Nov-2020), current quarter should be returned as `20204`, previous quarter as `20203`, next quarter as `20211`. It should be dynamic and should work for all the date/ month. I am trying with some approach like below but it doesn't seems to be working. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

```
curr_yrqtr=$(date +%Y)$(( ($(date +%-m)-1)/3+1 ))
prev_yrqtr=$(date -d "-1 month" +%Y)$(( ($(date -d "-1 month" +%-m)-1)/3+1 ))
```

Comment: consider running a google search on `bash date format quarter` and then peruse all the hits (including quite a few SE/SO Q&A's)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing how the question has several different flags (`bash`, `ksh`, `perl`), I'm guessing the OP is open to any solution that generates the desired results.

If the OP's version of `date` includes support for the `%q` (quarter) format:

```
read -r curr_year curr_qtr < <(date '+%Y %q')
```

If the OP's version of `date` does not support the `%q` (quarter) format:

```
read -r curr_year curr_month < <(date '+%Y %m')
curr_qtr=$((curr_month / 3 + 1))
```

From here the rest of the code is the same regardless of the version of `date`:

```
prev_year="${curr_year}"
prev_qtr=$((curr_qtr - 1))

next_year="${curr_year}"
next_qtr=$((curr_qtr + 1))

case "${curr_qtr}" in
    1) prev_year=$((curr_year - 1)) ; prev_qtr=4 ;;
    4) next_year=$((curr_year + 1)) ; next_qtr=1 ;;
esac

echo "previous quarter : ${prev_year}${prev_qtr}"
echo "current  quarter : ${curr_year}${curr_qtr}"
echo "next     quarter : ${next_year}${next_qtr}"
```

Running the above where 'today' == 2 Nov 2020:

```
previous quarter : 20203
current  quarter : 20204
next     quarter : 20211
```

Comment: Can you please let me know the Shell script solution if possible. %q is not working for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @prabu ; updated to include alternative code in case `date` does not support the `%q` format

Answer (score 1):

Your question has many different tags, this is a Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @now = localtime( time );

my $quarter = 1 + ($now[4]+1) % 4;
my $year = $now[5] + 1900;

my @q_prev = $quarter == 1 ? ($year-1, 4) : ($year, $quarter-1);
my @q_next = $quarter == 4 ? ($year+1, 1) : ($year, $quarter+1);

printf "%d%d\n", @q_prev;
printf "%d%d\n", $year, $quarter;
printf "%d%d\n", @q_next;
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I have just included PERL for higher possibility of answers. I have removed it now. Can you please let me know the Shell Script solution if possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the day to 01 and then - or + 3 months to get the correct year and month number.

```
curr_yrqtr=$(date +%Y)$(($(date +%-m)/3+1))
prev_yrqtr=$(date -d "$(date +%Y%m01) -3 months" +%Y)$(($(date -d "$(date +%Y%m01) -3 months" +%-m)/3+1))
next_yrqtr=$(date -d "$(date +%Y%m01) +3 months" +%Y)$(($(date -d "$(date +%Y%m01) +3 months" +%-m)/3+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using portable shell script you can say:

```sh
yrmo=$(date '+%Y%m')
: $((yr = yrmo / 100))  $((mo = yrmo % 100))
# let p = quarter number less 1 (0..3)
: $(( p = (mo-1)/3 ))
printf '%d-%02d:\t%d%d\t%d%d\t%d%d\n' \
        "$yr" "$mo" \
        $(( yr-(p<1) )) $(( p<1 ? 4 : p+0 )) \
        $(( yr ))       $(( p+1 )) \
        $(( yr+(p>2) )) $(( p>2 ? 1 : p+2 ))
```

which adjusts the year if in 1st or 4th quarter (`p` being 0 or 3)
and folds the quarter into range 1..4.

Output:

```
2020-11:    20203   20204   20211
```